# Cardano Wallet setup - No such directory

Tags: wallet

Hi am trying to setup cardano-wallet locally through wsl2 via this guide https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-wallet/

On the step where it asks to enter this command `cp -p "dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.10.4/cardano-wallet-2021.5.26/x/cardano-wallet/build/cardano-wallet/cardano-wallet" ~/.local/bin/`  I get an error stating the file directory cannot be found. `cabal build all` leaves me with two cardano wallet folders that i think maybe in need to point to

- dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.10.4/cardano-wallet-launcher-2021.9.9
- dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.10.4/cardano-wallet-core-2021.9.9

Is the specified directory somewhere in there? there is no `x/cardano-wallet/build/cardano-wallet/cardano-wallet` to be seen :(

Note: I did configure cabal with `cabal configure --with-compiler=ghc-8.10.4"` instead of `cabal configure --with-compiler=ghc-8.10.4 --constraint="random<1.2"` as the prior was not letting me sucessfully build.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, seems very unexpected. But yes, pay attention to the version number changes and adjust accordingly. Anyway, what does this command reveal, if anything? `find ~/ -name cardano-wallet`

Comment: Autocorrect capitalized Cardano, if you were searching for that... try again plz.

Comment: @LouisWaweru a few different paths which look promising. But all under ghc 8.10.7. /home/isaac/cardano-src/cardano-wallet
/home/isaac/cardano-src/cardano-wallet/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.10.7/cardano-wallet-2021.9.9/x/cardano-wallet
/home/isaac/cardano-src/cardano-wallet/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.10.7/cardano-wallet-2021.9.9/x/cardano-wallet/build/cardano-wallet
/home/isaac/cardano-src/cardano-wallet/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.10.7/cardano-wallet-2021.9.9/x/cardano-wallet/build/cardano-wallet/cardano-wallet

Comment: @LouisWaweru also definitely on the right branch v2021-09-09

Comment: Honestly, I’m not even going to try to look at this on my phone 

Comment: Hahhaha fair. pretty much theyre in the folder ghc-8.10.7 not ghc-8.10.4 for some reason

Comment: I can't see a reason not to use `ghc-8.10.7` so I'll give it a try with the latest wallet tag, and propose updating the docs... It's not a major nor a minor version change, so what harm can it do?

Answer (score 1):

## Working Backwards

Major edit: There is a reason the docs are explicit about `ghc-8.10.4`. I just hit this weird error that went away after downgrading from 8.10.7:

```
$ cabal build all
cabal: Cannot find the program 'ghc'. User-specified path 'ghc-8.10.5' does
not refer to an executable and the program is not on the system path.
```

Edit: I think you actually did what you were supposed to do and checked out the latest tag (at the time of writing): https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/tree/v2021-09-09

Yeah, like I was saying, the guides don't always keep up with versions and dependencies. I'm sure the wallet built with `ghc-8.10.7` is completely fine, and worth testing out to let the GitHub maintainers know to update their docs.

## Solution for You

However, they are probably very well aware of this, and so if must, you can always switch to 8.10.4:

```
ghcup install ghc 8.10.4
ghcup set ghc 8.10.4
```

You can start again from:

`cabal configure --with-compiler=ghc-8.10.4`

(Or even the next line).

Now, their guide should match up as they intended. However, I'd still ask about using 8.10.7... and maybe updating the guide depending on the answer.

If you need to reclaim space, you can remove some stuff:

```
ghcup rm ghc 8.10.7
du -hs ~/.cabal
rm -rf ./cabal
```

I would just replace with `2021.5.26` with `2021.9.9`, andw= when all is done, run `cardano-wallet version` to see that you are in fact on the latest build.

```
$ cp -d "dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.10.4/cardano-wallet-2021.9.9/x/cardano-wallet/build/cardano-wallet/cardano-wallet" ~/.local/bin/
$ cardano-wallet version
v2021-09-09 (git revision: 011a258c1b5ba57ca70f13346109ce3074820032)
```